# Reading a char array provides different results in and out of ISR

Tags: pic, c

I'm having problems reading a char array inside of an ISR. I'm using PIC18F4680 and C18 compiler version 3.41.

The array has several elements which are populated from data read from an RTC and they should be later on used to generate data in another matrix which will be later on used to drive a 5x7 display.

My problem is that when I read the elements of the array, I get one set of values in the ISR and another outside of the ISR.

Here's the output of what I'm getting:

```
 1  1
 0  0
 0  0     

 1  1
 0  0
 0  0     

 1  1
 0  0
 0  0     

 ******************* 
 1  7
 0  0
 0  0    


 ******************* 
 1  1
 0  0
 0  0     

 1  1
 0  0
 0  0     

 1  1
 0  0
 0  0
```

The top line is seconds, second line is minutes and third line is hours since the system was started.  The three lines with stars above and below them were send from the ISR. As we can see, the value of seconds was 11 before ISR, 17 in ISR and 11 after the ISR. I've also noticed that this never happens during first 10 seconds after start of a minute or during last 10 seconds of a minute. At other times the changes seem to happen at random.

Here's the relevant code:

```
k=0;//this is a sort of critical section
data[0]=from_seconds (data[0]);
data[1]=from_minutes (data[1]);
data[2]=from_hours (data[2]).time;
k=1;//if it's zero, ISR won't read the data

for (i=0;i<3;i++)
//I made sure here that the counter variable isn't used anywhere else
            {
              WriteUSART ( (data[i]/10)+48 );//Converting decimal into ASCII
              putrsUSART (" ");
              WriteUSART ( (data[i]%10)+48 );
              putrsUSART ("\r\n");
            }
            putrsUSART ("\r\n");
            putrsUSART ("\r\n");
            putrsUSART ("\r\n");
            putrsUSART ("\r\n");
```

Here's the ISR:

```
 if (INTCON3bits.INT1IF)
{
      if(k)//I know that I'll miss the interrupt if the k is zero, but I'll fix that later
        {
          fill_matrix (data[2],data[1], data[0]);

          putrsUSART ("\r\n");
          putrsUSART ("\r\n");
          putrsUSART ("*******************");
          putrsUSART ("\r\n");

          for (j=0;j<3;j++)
            {
              WriteUSART ( (data[j]/10)+48 );
              putrsUSART (" ");
              WriteUSART ( (data[j]%10)+48 );
              putrsUSART ("\r\n");
            }
            putrsUSART ("\r\n");
            putrsUSART ("\r\n");
            putrsUSART ("\r\n");
            putrsUSART ("*******************");
            putrsUSART ("\r\n");
        }
        INTCON3bits.INT1IF=0;
}
```

Any ideas what could be happening here?

UPDATE:

About tcrosley's comment:
The part separated by exclamation marks is read by the reading ISR and the part separated by stars is made by the writing ISR.

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
   0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0  0



 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 


 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
   0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0  0



 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 


 ******************* 
   1  [  _  [  1
   t  @  4  0  [
   „  0  4  1  Z
   t  1  _  1  Z
   t  0  5  0  Z
   t  0  5  0  Z
   0  t  _  Z  0



 ******************* 


 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
   1  [  _  [  1
   t  @  4  0  [
   „  0  4  1  Z
   t  1  _  1  Z
   t  0  5  0  Z
   t  0  5  0  Z
   0  t  _  Z  0



 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 


 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
   1  [  _  [  1
   t  @  4  0  [
   „  0  4  1  Z
   t  1  _  1  Z
   t  0  5  0  Z
   t  0  5  0  Z
   0  t  _  Z  0



 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 

 ******************* 
   Q  ›    ›  Q
   t  @  ґ  0  ›
   „  0  ґ  Q  љ
   t  1    Q  љ
   t  0  Х  0  љ
   t  0  Х  0  љ
   0  t    љ  0



 ******************* 


 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
   Q  ›    ›  Q
   t  @  ґ  0  ›
   „  0  ґ  Q  љ
   t  1    Q  љ
   t  0  Х  0  љ
   t  0  Х  0  љ
   0  t    љ  0



 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 


 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
   Q  ›    ›  Q
   t  @  ґ  0  ›
   „  0  ґ  Q  љ
   t  1    Q  љ
   t  0  Х  0  љ
   t  0  Х  0  љ
   0  t    љ  0



 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 


 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
   Q  ›    ›  Q
   t  @  ґ  0  ›
   „  0  ґ  Q  љ
   t  1    Q  љ
   t  0  Х  0  љ
   t  0  Х  0  љ
   0  t    љ  0



 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 


 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
   Q  ›    ›  Q
   t  @  ґ  0  ›
   „  0  ґ  Q  љ
   t  1    Q  љ
   t  0  Х  0  љ
   t  0  Х  0  љ
   0  t    љ  0



 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 


 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
   Q  ›    ›  Q
   t  @  ґ  0  ›
   „  0  ґ  Q  љ
   t  1    Q  љ
   t  0  Х  0  љ
   t  0  Х  0  љ
   0  t    љ  0



 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 


 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
   Q  ›    ›  Q
   t  @  ґ  0  ›
   „  0  ґ  Q  љ
   t  1    Q  љ
   t  0  Х  0  љ
   t  0  Х  0  љ
   0  t    љ  0



 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 


 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
   Q  ›    ›  Q
   t  @  ґ  0  ›
   „  0  ґ  Q  љ
   t  1    Q  љ
   t  0  Х  0  љ
   t  0  Х  0  љ
   0  t    љ  0



 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 


 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
   Q  ›    ›  Q
   t  @  ґ  0  ›
   „  0  ґ  Q  љ
   t  1    Q  љ
   t  0  Х  0  љ
   t  0  Х  0  љ
   0  t    љ  0



 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 


 ******************* 
   P  ћ    ћ  P
   „  1  ±  0  ћ
   …  0  ±  P  ћ
   „  0    P  ћ
   „  0  С  0  ћ
   „  0  С  0  ћ
   0  „    ћ  0



 ******************* 


 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
   P  ћ    ћ  P
   „  1  ±  0  ћ
   …  0  ±  P  ћ
   „  0    P  ћ
   „  0  С  0  ћ
   „  0  С  0  ћ
   0  „    ћ  0



 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 


 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
   P  ћ    ћ  P
   „  1  ±  0  ћ
   …  0  ±  P  ћ
   „  0    P  ћ
   „  0  С  0  ћ
   „  0  С  0  ћ
   0  „    ћ  0



 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 


 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
   P  ћ    ћ  P
   „  1  ±  0  ћ
   …  0  ±  P  ћ
   „  0    P  ћ
   „  0  С  0  ћ
   „  0  С  0  ћ
   0  „    ћ  0



 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 


 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
   P  ћ    ћ  P
   „  1  ±  0  ћ
   …  0  ±  P  ћ
   „  0    P  ћ
   „  0  С  0  ћ
   „  0  С  0  ћ
   0  „    ћ  0



 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 


 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
   P  ћ    ћ  P
   „  1  ±  0  ћ
   …  0  ±  P  ћ
   „  0    P  ћ
   „  0  С  0  ћ
   „  0  С  0  ћ
   0  „    ћ  0



 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

As far as I see, the reading ISR always gets the correct data from the matrix, even after several tens of seconds.

Comment: In your ISR, what does the line "fill_matrix (data[2],data[1], data[0]);" do?

Comment: @tcrosley It reads the three chars given to it as arguments and then fills the data into a matrix which will later on be used to draw show images on displays.

Comment: @tcrosley I have a char [7][5] matrix and each char in it contains bits which will be sent to shift registers controlling the 5x7 displays. Another interrupt reads the data from the matrix and sends it to the shift registers and turns on individual dots.

Comment: What happens if you dump out the contents of the matrix, either in this ISR or the other ISR that reads the matrix?

Comment: is `k` volatile?

Comment: @tcrosley The data written by the writing ISR appears correctly inside the reading ISR.

Comment: @Thorn Yes, it is.

Comment: It shouldn't matter if k and data are volatile, since the ISR is not writing to them, right?  I thought volatile is only really important if the ISR will be changing a variable.  And even then it's only useful if your compiler is performing optimizations.  Still might be worth adding volatile just to be safe anyway

Comment: @ajs410 Well the optimizations are turned down to allow easier debugging. Anyway, I set the matrix and array to be volatile in addition to k and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: What's up with "data[0]=from_seconds (data[0]);"?  Where is data[0] *actually* being written to?

Comment: @ajs410 Into data[0]. I'm just converting it from the format provided by the RTC into format I use for later processing.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  What writes to data[0] before your from_seconds line?  From the code you've shown, the only thing that writes to data[0] depends on data[0] itself!  Some other code somewhere else must be writing into data[0], otherwise there's no way for new data to get processed.

Comment: @ajs410 Oh you meant that... I have a function that reads data from the RTC I have and it writes it to the data array which is then modified by the code I've shown and then used to generate the matrix which will contain the data to be displayed.

Comment: I would avoid re-using the same array for handling data conversions.  I fear that your ISR is running after the RTC value is loaded and before from_seconds is executed (unless your "critical section" makes reading the RTC and converting it into an "atomic" operation).  This means the ISR could see RTC data.  Load RTC data into a separate array, then convert into your data array in the "critical section".

Comment: @ajs410 Good line of thought. Post it as an answer and I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
k=0;//this is a sort of critical section
data[0]=from_seconds (data[0]);
data[1]=from_minutes (data[1]);
data[2]=from_hours (data[2]).time;
k=1;//if it's zero, ISR won't read the data
```

Where does data[0] get its initial value from?  OP comments imply it is first loaded with RTC data, then gets converted here into a different format.  But where is the RTC data loaded?

In order to re-use the array, both loading RTC data and converting should happen within the "critical section".  Otherwise, it would be possible for the ISR to fire between being loaded with RTC data and being converted.  In general, I frown on re-using data arrays like that, especially with ISRs because an ISR will go out of its way to fire at the worst possible time.

Instead, it should work more on a handshaking philosophy.  First, load an otherwise-unused array with the RTC data.  Then, do the conversion inside the critical section.  This ensures that at any and every possible time that the ISR could fire, the values in the data array will always be correct.

As a bonus, I would recommend against this type of critical section approach.  Instead, if you need this sort of functionality, set INTCON3bits.INT1IE = 0 so that only this interrupt is masked.  The interrupt flag will still be set, and when you set INTCON3bits.INT1IE = 1 later on, the interrupt will fire as expected.

Comment: Looks like this was the problem after all. Thanks a lot!